# How to get a variable out a a tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

There are some similar questions already on this site. The difference is that I'm coding the Tkinter window as a class. Then making an instance in another file. For example:

```
import file

gui = file.Window()
gui.mainloop()
# The program continues, using the variables chosen by the user in the previous window.
```

while `file` is another file that contains the window code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, master):
        # some code

    def mainWidgets(self):
        self.body = Body(self)
        self.body.grid(row=0, column=0)

class Body(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        # Labels entries and selections
        self.boton_enviar = tk.Button(self, text='Send', command=self.send)
        self.boton_enviar.grid()

    def send(self):
        variables = self.variables
        # What code do I add here?
        self.quit()
```

So I want to close the window when clicking the 'Send' button but I need to retrieve some variables to use in the main program. How can I do this ?

Comment: `gui.<your variable>`. Read [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: the variables are set by the user so `gui.<your variable>` before `gui.mainloop()` returns an error.

Comment: ***"before `gui.mainloop()`"***: Why **before**, `.mainloop()` is blocking, you asked ***"want to close the window ... retrieve some variables"***? Do it **after**.